# Do $SU(n) \to \operatorname{Spin}(2n)$ and $SU(n) \to O(2n)$ induces an embedding of $SU(n)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Question: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spin}{Spin}$

- Does $SU(n) \to \Spin(2n)$  induces an embedding of $SU(n) \subset \Spin(2n)$?
- Do  $SU(n) \to  O(2n)$ induces an embedding of $SU(n) \subset O(2n)$?

### Some info:

Here the spin group $\Spin(2n)$ has a $\mathbf{Z}_2$ center as a normal subgroup such that $\Spin(2n)/\mathbf{Z}_2=SO(2n).$
Potentially there is a lift as a commutative diagram.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  & \Spin(2n)\\
          &\nearrow &           \downarrow\\
  SU(n) & \longrightarrow & SO(2n)
\end{array}.
$$

Here the orthogonal group $O(2n)$ has a normal $SO(2n)$ subgroup such that $O(2n)/SO(2n)=\mathbf{Z}_2.$ Potentially there is a lift (not sure my description of lift is precise?) as a commutative diagram.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  & O(2n)\\
          &\nearrow &           \uparrow\\
  SU(n) & \longrightarrow & SO(2n)
\end{array}.
$$

We can take the complex vector space $\mathbb C^n$ as $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and recall that the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is the real part of the standard Hermitian inner product on  $\mathbb C^n$. So this shows that
$$SU(n) \subset SO(2n)$$
(maybe this also proves that $U(n) \subset  O(2n)$ as well? please clarify.)

I know the first homotopy group that
$$\pi_1(SU(n))=0, \; \forall  n \geq 1$$
$$\pi_1(SO(2))=\pi_1(O(2))=\pi_1(\Spin(2))=\mathbf{Z}, \; $$
$$\pi_1(SO(m))=\pi_1(O(m))=\mathbf{Z}_2, \; \forall  m \geq 3$$
$$\pi_1(\Spin(m))=0, \; \forall  m \geq 3.$$
Perhaps the fundamental group is crucial to understand whether the lift and the embedding are possible.