# Do $U(n) \to Spin(2n)$ and $U(n) \to O(2n)$ induces an embedding of $U(n)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Follow up [Do $SU(n) \to \operatorname{Spin}(2n)$ and $SU(n) \to O(2n)$ induces an embedding of $SU(n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217648/955245), now I ask a more restricted thus more difficult version of question on $U(n)$ instead of $SU(n)$:

- Does $U(n) \to  Spin(2n)$  induces an embedding of $U(n) \subset Spin(2n)$?
- Do  $U(n) \to  O(2n)$ induces an embedding of $U(n) \subset O(2n)$?

Here the spin group $Spin(2n)$ has a $\mathbf{Z}_2$ center such that $Spin(2n)/\mathbf{Z}_2=SO(2n).$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  & Spin(2n)\\
          &\nearrow &           \downarrow\\
  U(n) & \longrightarrow & SO(2n)
\end{array}.
$$

Here the orthogonal group $O(2n)$ has a normal $SO(2n)$ subgroup such that $O(2n)/SO(2n)=\mathbf{Z}_2.$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  & O(2n)\\
          &\nearrow &           \uparrow\\
  U(n) & \longrightarrow & SO(2n)
\end{array}.
$$

We can take the complex vector space $\mathbb C^n$ as $\mathbb R^{2n}$ and recall that the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is the real part of the standard Hermitian inner product on  $\mathbb C^n$. So this shows that
$$U(n) \subset SO(2n)$$
(maybe this also proves that $U(n) \subset  O(2n)$ as well? please clarify.)

I know the first homotopy group that
$$\pi_1(U(n))=\mathbf{Z}, \; \forall  n \geq 1$$
$$\pi_1(SO(2))=\pi_1(O(2))=\pi_1(Spin(2))=\mathbf{Z}, \; $$
$$\pi_1(SO(m))=\pi_1(O(m))=\mathbf{Z}_2, \; \forall  m \geq 3$$
$$\pi_1(Spin(m))=0, \; \forall  m \geq 3.$$
Perhaps the fundamental group is crucial to understand whether the lift and the embedding are possible (?).

Comment: A lift on a covering space of an embedding is an embedding. This is easy to see, since the differential is the same, and injectivity follows from the fact that if a $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ must be.

Comment: You may want to review the definitions a bit as well. It should be clear, from the fact that $U(N)$ embeds in $SO(2N)$ that it does as well in $O(2N)$.  Your just increasing the size of the codomain, which always preserves embedding.

Comment: @pax, true, O(2n) contains the SO(2n) as a subgroup

Comment: But ()⊂(2) may be false - was your first comment consistent with what I said or no?